# Does Android disk encryption use device-specific keys (such as IMEI or model) to encrypt the disk?

Tags: data-recovery, encryption, disk-encryption

This question is about how disk encryption for Android 6.0 works.

**In short:** Does Android 6.0 disk encryption use any device-specific keys (such as IMEI or model) to encrypt the disk?

**In detail:**
I'm trying to recover data from a Nexus 5 phone with a damaged motherboard (due to short circuit).
It was running Android 6.0 with a disk that was encrypted using a user PIN (Device was shipped with an unencrypted Android 4.4).

To recover the data, I'm thinking to buy an SMD rework station to do a chip-off of the memory chip to a new Nexus 5 device, and then turn on the phone, enter the PIN, and get access to my files.

I'm trying to understand, since the disk was encrypted - would this work?
Would a new device with an old eMMC memory chip boot?

If disk encryption on Android **only** uses the user-entered PIN to encrypt the user-created data, I think this would work. If it uses device-specific values (such as IMEI or model) either in concatenation to the user-entered PIN or as a salt, soldering the old memory to a new device won't work.

According to [Full-Disk Encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk) in the android open-source documentation, it looks like in Android 5.0 to 9.0 only the user-created data is encrypted, but not the OS itself. The [Storing the encrypted key](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk#storing_the_encrypted_key) section says

> Hardware backing is implemented by using Trusted Execution Environment’s (TEE) signing capability. Previously, we encrypted the master key with a key generated by applying scrypt to the user's password and the stored salt. In order to make the key resilient against off-box attacks, we extend this algorithm by signing the resultant key with a stored TEE key.

Does this mean the encryption uses a hardware-specific key? An expert's help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As @alecxs said, you answered it in the last two words you quoted [TEE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_execution_environment). See [Trusty TEE](https://source.android.com/security/trusty)

Comment: https://www.j-michel.org/blog/2014/05/27/from-nand-chip-to-files

Comment: https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2018/05/demystifying-android-physical-acquisition

Comment: if you know for sure device is encrypted, try to fix the damaged motherboard. everything else is wasted time, as the encrypted dump is only decryptable on this unique source phone itself

Comment: If your device is running Android 6.0,why is it that you seek answers for Android 5 to 9?.please [edit] to clarify //This site works on a single Question model not multiple questions packaged in one question //You can split questions separately

Comment: fun fact/ yesterday flashed latest available stock ROM on Samsung Tablet SM-T555 Android 7.1.1 and this device remain unencrypted (completely stock with locked bootloader), which i thought encryption must enforced on all recent android - obviously not. afaik Nexus 5 is not encrypted, that's why i ask if you know for sure

Comment: can remember for Nexus 5 once there was a hack for Qualcomm's KeyMaster to extract the hardware backed key (CVE-2016-2431) https://bits-please.blogspot.com/2016/06/extracting-qualcomms-keymaster-keys.html if your device is still vulnerable you might be able to decrypt offline https://forensicswiki.xyz/wiki/index.php?title=How_To_Decrypt_Android_Full_Disk_Encryption#Locating_the_Encryption_Key

Comment: in case your encryption is scrypt only (no keymaster) hashcat https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-2270.html and santoku have scripts for bruteforce https://santoku-linux.com/howto/mobile-forensics/how-to-brute-force-android-encryption/#run-brute-force (although my previous comment is contradictory)

Comment: but the most straightforward seems TWRP. i believe the Nexus 5 was shipped with unlocked bootloader, so basically you "just" need to bring back this motherboard to life and enter fastboot mode, boot (or flash) TWRP and decrypt userdata partition

Comment: To add because it covers similar ground, KeyMaster 3.0 (introduced in Android 8.0) has an optional (but highly recommended) feature [ID attestation](https://source.android.com/security/keystore/attestation#id-attestation) which does tie hardware-specific ids into verified boot. That being said, I haven't looked if there exists a similar type of enforcement for Android 6.0 and below.